# Decode UTF-8 exported XML nodes (Persian) by PHP

Tags: php, xml, utf-8, decode, persian

I have an exported XML file in Persian from Wordpress, one node is like this:

> %d8%aa%d9%81%d8%a7%d9%88%d8%aa-%d8%a8%d8%b1%d8%a7%d8%aa-%d9%88-%d8%a7%d9%84-%d8%b3%db%8c-%d8%af%d8%b1-%da%86%db%8c%d8%b3%d8%aa%d8%9f

How can I decode it to Persian by PHP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `urldecode`

```
$text = urldecode('%d8%aa%d9%81%d8%a7%d9%88%d8%aa-%d8%a8%d8%b1%d8%a7%d8%aa-%d9%88-%d8%a7%d9%84-%d8%b3%db%8c-%d8%af%d8%b1-%da%86%db%8c%d8%b3%d8%aa%d8%9f');
```

http://codepad.org/ckZV8p76